# Connexion create object instance

Tags: python-3.x, flask, swagger, openapi, connexion

I am working on refactoring a flask app which uses *connexion* package for the RESTful API. Previously the code base was function based and I`m refactoring it with some OOP design principles.

```
app = connexion.App(__name__)
app.add_api(
 os.path.join(global_variables.ROOT_DIR, "openapi.yaml"),
 pythonic_params=True,
 validate_responses=VALIDATE_RESPONSES,
 validator_map={"parameter": request_parameter_validator.RequestParameterValidator},
)
```

In the `openapi.yaml` the `operationId` specifies the full path to the class method which handles the request, but it throws the error:

```
TypeError: be_autocomplete_handler() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

How can I create an instance of that class in this case and pass it in the `parameters` field? Also, I do not pass any parameters in the constructor for now.

However, is there a preferred workflow in this case? Rather than creating an object instance?